# SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired

Tags: websphere

We are getting the following error message in SystemOut.log :

```
SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired.  Exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at com.ibm.jsse2.o.a(o.java:9)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:294)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:172)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.j(SSLEngineImpl.java:12)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.b(SSLEngineImpl.java:113)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.a(SSLEngineImpl.java:476)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLEngineImpl.unwrap(SSLEngineImpl.java:95)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:14)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLUtils.handleHandshake(SSLUtils.java:1016)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.readyInbound(SSLConnectionLink.java:566)
    at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLConnectionLink.ready(SSLConnectionLink.java:295)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.sendToDiscriminators(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:214)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.complete(NewConnectionInitialReadCallback.java:113)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
```

There are two servers 'A' and 'B', 'A' is trying to communicate with B to get the data. (A Web application is deployed in 'A' and it is trying to communicate with 'B').

Can anyone help resolve this?

Comment: Server A and B are not in the same cell, correct? Have you established SSL trust between server A and B?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the ssl cert from Server B into ServerA's trustStore.