# defining 2 ports in deployment.yaml in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-deployment

I have a docker image from I am doing

```
docker run --name test -h test -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install
```

I am trying to put into a kubernetes deploy file and I have this:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websphere
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: websphere
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: websphere
        image: ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9443
        resources:
          requests: 
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
        imagePullPolicy: Always
```

my service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websphere
  labels:
    app: websphere
spec:
  type: NodePort #Exposes the service as a node ports
  ports:
  - port: 9443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9443
  selector:
    app: websphere
```

May I have guidance on how to map 2 ports in my deployment file?

Answer (score 16):

You can add as many ports as you need.

Here your `deployment.yml`:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: websphere
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: websphere
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: websphere
        image: ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9043
        - containerPort: 9443
        resources:
          requests: 
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
          limits:
            memory: 500Mi
            cpu: 0.5
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
```

Here your `service.yml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: websphere
  labels:
    app: websphere
spec:
  type: NodePort #Exposes the service as a node ports
  ports:
  - port: 9043
    name: hello
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9043
    nodePort: 30043
  - port: 9443
    name: privet
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9443
    nodePort: 30443
  selector:
    app: websphere
```

Check on your kubernetes `api-server` configuration what is the range for nodePorts (usually `30000-32767`, but it's configurable).

**EDIT**

If I remove from deployment.yml the `resources` section, it starts correctly (after about 5 mins).
Here a snippet of the logs:

> [9/10/18 8:08:06:004 UTC] 00000051 webcontainer  I
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I:
>   Web Module Default Web Application has been bound to
>   default_host[*:9080,*:80,*:9443,*:506 0,*:5061,*:443].

Problems come connecting to it (I use ingress with traefik), because of certificates (I suppose):

> [9/10/18 10:15:08:413 UTC] 000000a4 SSLHandshakeE E   SSLC0008E:
>   Unable to initialize SSL connection.  Unauthorized access was denied
>   or security settings have expired.  Exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext
>   connection?

To solve that (I didn't go further) this may help: [SSLHandshakeE E SSLC0008E: Unable to initialize SSL connection. Unauthorized access was denied or security settings have expired](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37025096/sslhandshakee-e-sslc0008e-unable-to-initialize-ssl-connection-unauthorized-acc)

Trying to connect with `port-forward`:

[image]

and using dthe browser to connect, I land on this page:

[image]

Comment: Hi Nicola, I tried to do $ kubectl apply -f WB_Sphere_service.yml
The Service "websphere" is invalid:
* spec.ports[0].name: Required value
* spec.ports[1].name: Required value

Comment: Thank you NIcola. I tried to do a port forward to my local host: kubectl port-forward websphere-7874884868-ntz54 9043:9043 9443:9443
but it told me that 043 -> 9043: error forwarding port 9043 to pod 7e184665bf11f95ee02d07d40224a52368aa6b50240f0c7faf1a335d5b87a86e, uid : exit status 1: 2018/09/09 16:49:06 socat[1668] E connect(5, AF=2 127.0.0.1:9043, 16): Connection refused

Comment: Does your image ibmcom/websphere-traditional open those port numbers?

Comment: yes based on documentation. 

docker run --name test -h test -p 9043:9043 -p 9443:9443 -d \
  ibmcom/websphere-traditional:install

Comment: I added some info.

Comment: i got that too @nicola. But i tried to access the app and nothing happened . how did you access it?

https://<master ip>:30043/ibm/console/login.do?action=secure

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179748/discussion-between-nicola-ben-and-adam).

Answer (score 3):

Well in kubernetes you can define your ports using #port label. This label comes under ports configuration in your deployment. According to the configurations you can simply define any numbers of ports you wish. Following example shows how to define two ports.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: MyApp
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 9376
    - name: https
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 9377
```